API is struck at searching knowledge base how I can get the final answer
I am trying Watson Assistant APIs V2 and using Session based message API
After sending a message I am getting 200 OK with below response
{
"response_type": "text",
"text": "Searching knowledge base, retrieving answer and generating a response."
}
I want to know how I can get the final result.
{{wa_url}}/v2/assistants/{{environment_id}}/sessions/a13d1674-cc83-4c99-9b19-f09178367868/message?version={{version}}
{
"response_type": "text",
"text": "Searching knowledge base, retrieving answer and generating a response."
}
I want to know how I can get the final result.
